# "Transaction Script" , "Table Module" and "Domain Model" in order to make business components in business layer?

Tags: .net

I'm studying "Transaction Script", "Table Module" and "Domain Model" but it seems somehow complicated to me.

Could you please give me an example which compares these three patterns?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same question and I thought of the following example:

Imagine an online shop app with the following use cases:

1. User buys a product

   - browses products
   - puts one or more into cart
   - checks out (enters payment and shipping information etc.)
2. User edits their profile

   - change password
   - enter/update payment information

With **Transaction Script** we would have one class per use case and one function per transaction/request!

```
class BuyProduct {
  List getProducts(string filter) { /* some database query */ }
  void putInCart(int productId, int amount) { ... }
  void checkout(...) {...}
}
class EditProfile {
  void changePassword(string newpwHash) { ... }
  void updatePaymentInfo(...) {...}
}
```

This makes sense when there is not much logic to implement and all we need is a set of grouped database transactions!
(and where you do not need to reuse code often)

With **Domain Model** we would instead map the reality on domain objects.
We would have classes for User, Product, ShoppingCart, ProductFilter, PaymentInformation, ...
These classes have functions performing tasks which relate to the class.

for example:

```
class User {
  string getPaymentInfo() {...}
  void updatePaymentInfo() {...}
}
```

The functions could either perform the database queries themselves or delegate them to a  persistence layer for example.

This approach makes sense for very complicated apps with a lot of logic and lots of situations where you would want to reuse code often.

With **Table Module** we would instead map database tables to objects.

In this case for example there could be classes for the product table, the User Table and the orders table (which keeps track of completed orders and their state).
Not only tables, but also customized database views, and Transactions/Requests can be mapped to classes/objects.

A simple example:

```
class ProductTable {
  List getProducts(string filter)
  void updateAmountAvailable(int productId, int newAmount) {...} // call after someone bought a product to update it's availability
  ...
}
```

This makes sense for small applications with a lot of work/logic on the database.
But it does not scale well with complexity.

Overall:
For small applications use tansaction script. Domain model is the best for very complex applications.
Table Module is (to my knowledge) rather uncommon and it might be better to use ORM.

Answer (score 5):

I hope you're referring to Fowler's book on the same - http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/

- Transaction Script is primarily procedural.. So you'd have one function/script that sequentially does steps (each of which effect some change)
- Domain Model is OO and requires the most work - you need to come up with a shared language and an object model that reflects the objects of interest in the domain.
- Table Module is new to me. It also looks OO except for the fact that it places more importance on the DB Schema.. The Table-Module-Object looks like a GateKeeper to a particular DB Table. All logic associated and operating primarily on the data in a DB table are housed in the corresponding TableModuleObject. Quoting from the link

> The primary distinction with Domain
>   Model (116) is that, if you have many
>   orders, a Domain Model (116) will have
>   one order object per order while a
>   Table Module will have one object to
>   handle all orders.